# jquery not working changing css attributes in magento

Tags: jquery, magento, magento-1.7

I have the following code running on [my site](http://foryourc-store.com/advance-tabco-wall-mounted-hand-sink-splash-faucet.html):

```
<style>
#main {background-color:#000000; border-top: 0;
padding-bottom: 20px;
min-height: 350px;}

.col-main {float: left;
width: 740px;
padding: 0 0 1px;
color:#FFFFFF;
background-color:#AABBCC;}

.col-right {float: right;
width: 200px;
padding: 0 0 1px;
color:#0F0F0F;
background-color:#DDEEFF;}

img {height:250px; width:250px;}
h1 {color: #ddeeff;}
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery.noConflict();
                   if (jQuery(".col-right").height() > jQuery(".col-main").height())

                                          {
jQuery(".col-main").height(jQuery(".col-right").height());
}
else {
jQuery(".col-right").height(jQuery(".col-main").height());
}

</script>

<div id="main"><h1>Main</h1>
<div class="col-main"><img src="http://foryourc-  store.com/media/favicon/default/FYCS_icon-01.png"/>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin consequat fermentum    nunc a eleifend. Phasellus ut est at justo porttitor gravida. Praesent ut placerat lacus. Etiam consectetur tortor vel nibh sodales semper. Praesent quam magna, pharetra non viverra et, porta a nisi. Aenean et mi ante. Duis a nunc metus, at hendrerit quam. Aenean molestie orci placerat mauris varius non cursus ipsum commodo. Donec sit amet ultrices ligula. Nam egestas ligula vitae justo scelerisque pulvinar. Nunc vestibulum fermentum ligula, vel consequat velit lobortis sed. Suspendisse et dolor lectus, sed dignissim justo. Vivamus rhoncus volutpat rutrum. Quisque pretium mi in enim bibendum in ultrices mi molestie.</div>

<div class="col-right"><img src="http://foryourc-store.com/media/favicon/default/FYCS_icon-01.png">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin consequat fermentum nunc a eleifend. Phasellus ut est at justo porttitor gravida. Praesent ut placerat lacus. Etiam consectetur tortor vel nibh sodales semper. Praesent quam magna, pharetra non viverra et, porta a nisi. Aenean et mi ante. Duis a nunc metus, at hendrerit quam. Aenean molestie orci placerat mauris varius non cursus ipsum commodo. Donec sit amet ultrices ligula. Nam egestas ligula vitae justo scelerisque pulvinar. Nunc vestibulum fermentum ligula, vel consequat velit lobortis sed. Suspendisse et dolor lectus, sed dignissim justo. Vivamus rhoncus volutpat rutrum. Quisque pretium mi in enim bibendum in ultrices mi molestie.<br>Integer pharetra sapien metus. Mauris bibendum eleifend luctus. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Pellentesque elementum lobortis luctus. Duis tristique leo sed velit commodo eu consequat magna eleifend. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Vestibulum sed neque a tellus auctor viverra sit amet sit amet dui. Aliquam dui mi, iaculis sit amet sagittis et, iaculis eu lacus. Morbi viverra tellus non nisl ultrices interdum. Praesent in turpis non justo mollis elementum vel eget velit. Aliquam pulvinar hendrerit tincidunt. Quisque tortor quam, lacinia ut elementum in, lacinia at arcu. Integer porta tincidunt urna nec semper. Vivamus gravida odio id ante adipiscing eu ultricies elit eleifend. Nulla lectus quam, malesuada sed rutrum ac, placerat sed mi. Donec bibendum sagittis dapibus.</div></div>
```

I am running Magento CE 1.7.0.2. The code is working fine here: http://jsfiddle.net/scoosethemoose/YxNwm/

Please help me to determine what is not working correctly. Thank you in advance.

Comment: see in your console their js error for jcarousel which is use in your custom.js whereas you have not added jcarousel library

Comment: your head end tag and body start tag is between script tag correct that error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should run the code in your page on `$(window).load()` like the fiddle does.

Before the load-event you can't retrieve the final dimensions of the elements for sure, because the page didn't finish the rendering-process yet.

Currently your script works(but not as expected), check the .col-right inside firebug, and you will see that a height has been assigned to the element, so your script was running the else-branch.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I did get it working using window.load.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are using this http://sorgalla.com/jcarousel/

You are getting on error on jQuery('#featured').jcarousel(); because the jcarousel plugin library doesn't seem to be included (if you view source for jquery.jcarousel.min.js or jcarousel*.js )

You are also loading **2 different copy of jQuery** - Need to remove one

- foryourc-store.com/js/jquery/jquery-latest.js (ver 1.8.2)
- skin/frontend/base/default/ig_lightbox2/js/jquery-1.6.2.min.js

Also you could creates a different alias for jQuery to use

```
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
// Do something with jQuery
$j(".col-main").height($j(".col-right").height());   
// instead of jQuery(".col-main").height(jQuery(".col-right").height());
//then use magento prototype with
$("content").style.display = 'none';
```

Comment: Thank you. I corrected the issue by adding jcarousel and removing one copy of jQuery from loading.

Answer (score 0):

```
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
$j(window).load(function() {
if ($j(".col-right").height() > $j(".col-main").height())

{
    $j(".col-main").height($j(".col-right").height());
}
else {
    $j(".col-right").height($j(".col-main").height());
}
});​
```

This solved it for me.